# Mocking in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

```
module gameSystem
 Class client
....
...
...

def accounts_by_id(account_id)

      response = query_account(CGI.escape(account_id))
      JSON.parse(response.body)
    end

...
...
...
end
```

I have the above code in which the accounts_by_id method lies inside the class Client. This method returns JSON.parse(response.body). Does anyone know how i can mock or use stub for this method in rails to return something.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Mocha to mock/stub functions for tests.  It would result in something like

`Client.any_instance.expects(:query_account).with("my-account-id").returns([some object to return])`

before the line that calls this function in your test.

However, this doesn't result in an actual assertion, just a failure if there are no function calls that match the expectation, which isn't ideal in my mind.  It would also fail if the account id passed in isn't what is expected (though the `with` isn't required.)

[Here](http://gofreerange.com/mocha/docs/Mocha/API.html) is the documentation for Mocha so you can better see how it is used.  I offer this answer because this has accomplished what I needed in the past, but I am very interested to see if there is a better solution out there.